# How to turn pcm audio into text using some lib written entirely in the C\C++ programming language?

Tags: c++, c, speech-recognition

How to turn pcm audio into text using some lib written entirely in the C\C++ programming language?

So I have pcm file. I want to turn it  into text. how to do it? (with  speech recognizer lib of your choise (BTW i need it to work extreamly fast)

So what do I need?

- Open Source Libs.
- Tutorials and blog articles on How to do/use it.

Comment: Your question is too broad, do your own research on Google or something like it, and when you hit a technical sticking point, come back and ask a more pointed question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Speech-Recognition-HOWTO.html

It gives some links to some libraries that use xwindows so they may well be written in c/c++